# Parse the data and put it into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a text file;

```
Date = 08152023
Time = 1692080569
ErrorCode = 500
ErrorDetails = internalerror

Date = 08162023
Time = 1692081569

Date = 08172023
Time = 1692081769
ErrorCode = 0
```

I would like to create a dataframe in the format below:

```
Date,Time,ErrorCode,ErrorDetails
08152023,1692080569,500,internalerror
08162023,1692081569,null,null
08172023,1692081769,0,null
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'my_file' your csv, you can read it with `\s*=\s*` as separator, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (pd
   .read_csv(my_file, sep=r'\s*=\s*', engine='python', header=None)
   .assign(n=lambda d: d[0].eq('Date').cumsum())
   .pivot(index='n', columns=0, values=1)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
       Date ErrorCode   ErrorDetails        Time
1  08152023       500  internalerror  1692080569
2  08162023       NaN            NaN  1692081569
3  08172023         0            NaN  1692081769
```

Variant to keep the original order of records:

```
out = (pd
   .read_csv(my_file, sep=r'\s*=\s*', engine='python', header=None)
   .assign(n=lambda d: d[0].eq('Date').cumsum(),
           col=lambda d: pd.factorize(d[0])[0])
   .pivot(index='n', columns=['col', 0], values=1)
   .droplevel('col', axis=1)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
       Date        Time ErrorCode   ErrorDetails
1  08152023  1692080569       500  internalerror
2  08162023  1692081569       NaN            NaN
3  08172023  1692081769         0            NaN
```

##### Alternative approach

Considering `\n\n` as record separator and only the first `=` as separator:

```
import re

with open(my_file) as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall('([^=\n]+?) *= *([^\n]+)', s))
                      for s in f.read().split('\n\n')])
```

Output:

```
       Date        Time ErrorCode ErrorDetails
0  08152023  1692080569       500   Date = 123
1  08162023  1692081569       NaN          NaN
2  08172023  1692081769         0          NaN
```

Used input:

```
Date = 08152023
Time = 1692080569
ErrorCode = 500
ErrorDetails = error: ABC = 123

Date = 08162023
Time = 1692081569

Date = 08172023
Time = 1692081769
ErrorCode = 0
```

Comment: You are making at least two assumptions: each chunk starts with `Date` and `=` can occur in unquoted sequences once in a string. IMO these are somewhat unreliable assumptions.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I don't rely on the chunks, I only rely on 'Date' and the `=` as separator, which seems a fair assumption given the example. If this is not, then OP should be more explicit.

Comment: When I look at the data like these the only I can say: "They're corrupted". Is `Date` always in chunks? Is it always at the first place? Are `ErrorDetails` strings without `=` in them? _Not sure._ That's why I think that your answer in its current state is not reliable.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I don't agree that this particular dataset seems "corrupted", but I get your point. I added another approach that relies on the double line break and the first `=` of each row as separator.